# Bootstrap 4 - add text carousel indicators

Tags: sass, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 4 and I can not change the Indicator to appear the text in relation to the item. I tried some options of other StackOverflow answers but none worked, if they can give an example of code working, thank you.
**Note:** I am using Sass with Webpack

```
 <div class="container">
    <div id="carouselContent" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ul class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselContent" data-slide-to="0" class="active">text1</li>
        <li data-target="#carouselContent" data-slide-to="1">text 1</li>
        <li data-target="#carouselContent" data-slide-to="2">text 2</li>
      </ul>

      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="carousel-item active text-center p-4">
          <h5>Text 1</h5>
          <p>
            text ...
          </p>
          <p>
            text ...
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item text-center p-4">
         <h5>Text 2</h5>
          <p>
            text ...
          </p>
          <p>
            text ...
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselContent" role="button" data-slide="prev" data-interval="4000">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselContent" role="button" data-slide="next" data-interval="4000">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to achieve?

The carousel indicator has styles to purposely hide the text:

```css
.carousel-indicators li {
    ...
    width: 30px;
    height: 3px;
    text-indent: -999px;
    ...
}
```

If you want to display the text, just remove them from the style.

[image]

**fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/7r4hecmy/